# How to rotate image in Android 2.2 webkit browser?

Tags: android, html, css, webkit

there seems to be an issue with Android >= 2.2. The webkit-based Browser does not rotate images.
In Android 2.1 the code below works. Maybe this is related to this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12451

Does anybody know a workaround how to get the image in my example (see html below) rotated in Webkit-based Browser (the Android standard Browser) in Android 2.2 and above?

Thank you a lot!!

Thomas

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    .imgclass {
                /* Firefox */
                -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) ;
                /* WebKit */
                -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
                /* Opera */
                -o-transform: rotate(30deg) ;
                /* Standard */
                transform: rotate(30deg) ;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="image.png" alt="" class="imgclass">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would probably give this a try with jquery rather than css... http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: this is working me in gingerbread browser